# DATE_FORMAT() mysql code will work in PHPMyAdmin but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a reporting method in PHP which is passed 2 parameters `$location` and `$weekYear`. `$weekYear` is a string that is formatted like `2015-W34`, i.e. the 34rth week of 2015. the sql code I am trying to run looks like:

```
   $sql = "SELECT 
          CONCAT(tutor.first_name, ' ', tutor.last_name) AS Student,
          CONCAT(tutor.first_name, ' ', tutor.last_name) AS Tutor,
               hours as HoursWorked, 
               DATE_FORMAT(work_date, '%a - %b %d') AS Day,
               DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%H') AS Hour, 
               DATE_FORMAT(start_time, '%i') AS Minute

          FROM timesheet_entry

          LEFT
          JOIN user
            AS student
            ON student.id = timesheet_entry.student_id

          LEFT
          JOIN user
            AS tutor
            ON tutor.id = timesheet_entry.tutor_id

         WHERE DATE_FORMAT(work_date,'%x-W%v') = '".$weekYear."'
           AND tutoring_location = '".$location."'
           AND work_type = 'instruction'
           AND (instruction_type = '1-on-1' OR instruction_type = 'group')";


        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

When I run the code in php I get no results returned
but when I echo out the $sql and then paste that into PhpMyAdmin I get the results I expect.

Furthermore if I remove the part

```
DATE_FORMAT(work_date,'%x-W%v') = '".$weekYear."'
```

the method runs, and returns more records than I want, but it runs nonetheless.

What about my `DATE_FORMAT()` is causing this query to malfunction?

Any help, advice, and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason you're using `DATE_FORMAT()` and not `WEEKYEAR()`?

Comment: Did you check for a mysql error in case of the 1st query run from your php code?

Comment: Can't see an obvious reason. Usually things like this are due to extra characters you don't notice, like spaces.

Comment: I tried adding and if else, with the else running a die(mysql_error() ) but it passed fine, and in general there are no sql errors. As far as WEEKYEAR(), is it possible to still add the dash and the W as formatting options?

Comment: Are you pointing to a different database in phpmyadmin than in your mysql script by any chance?

Comment: What's the value of your `$weekYear` variable? It could be causing the query to error out.

Comment: Looks like it is now working, i removed all unnecessary spaces and lines, very strange...but thank you all for the advice!

Answer (score -1):

i thing that you make a function for that mysql and php use your parameters $location and $weekYear because that your parameter WEEKYEAR is diferetn to the standar format and php or mysql dont function